# i got a problem while i'm trying to connect my flutter app to realtime databese using firebase

Tags: flutter, mobile

i got this  message :

> pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://"appname"-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app

while i was trying to connect my app to firebase realtime db ,the problem is i made the same steps that i used to create firebase database but it wont work ,i change the the database location many times but it wont work.

i don't know what to do ,i checked the packages and all but still says the same message if you have any idea please help.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Firebase Console, next to Project Overview is "Settings" button -> choose Project settings from menu.

Scroll down to "SDK setup and configuration", and download your google-services.json file again.

There should be "firebase_url" position now under "project_info".

If you still get an error, run:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`